# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Objects

Tags: servlets, primefaces, classnotfoundexception

I keep having this error message from glassfish. I am doing a chat on netbeans.
I tried google and most of the solutions are setting the class path. but it doesn't solve my problem :( my friend managed to run on his system though

I am using Log4J and primefaces.

```
WARNING: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Objects
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Objects
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent.processListener(SelectEvent.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.broadcast(AutoComplete.java:334)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Objects
    at entity.pojo.SimpleUser.hashCode(SimpleUser.java:132)
    at java.lang.Object.toString(Object.java:219)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at managedbean.chat.ChatBean.changeUser(ChatBean.java:319)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.Objects
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably implemented `hashCode()` in the `SimpleUser` class using Java 7's [`Objects.hash()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) method, and running this class on a Java 6 VM, which doesn't contain this class.